# How insert password when i try to read my Excel? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I try to read a Excel, but have password (i know password) how insert password to read excel. My Code is like that:

```
 Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            'Dim FolderPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Upload")

            Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~") & "\Upload\" & FileName
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath)

            Dim existingFile = New FileInfo(FilePath)
            Dim pack As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(existingFile)
            Dim workBook As ExcelWorkbook = pack.Workbook

            If workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0 Then ...
```

Error display on row:

> Dim pack As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(existingFile)

Error:

> Can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this
>   is an encrypted package, please supply the password

Comment: Just add password as second parameter to ExcelPackage constructor.

Comment: Dim pack As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(existingFile, "password") like that? Doesn't work @Arvo